# header image not proper due to min-height, can we fix it by jquery or so

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enLsab1r/) , when I minimize the window the height of the header is set to min-height:80px because of which in responsive there is white space below the header image, Is there any way without adding min-height the header height should adjust automatically?

**Note:** The reason why I add min-height:80px to header because in my css all wrapper are in fixed position

HTML -

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <img src="http://www.emedicalpoint.com/images/nav/sprite.jpg" alt="">
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    footer content here
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background: yellow none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  background: #414141 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to have a responsive div, you should avoid giving it a fixed height in pixel. try this:

```
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    header {
        background: yellow none repeat scroll 0 0;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content {
        bottom: 40px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Now, the percentages I have given are just for illustration purposes, you will have to find the right percentages.

Comment: Actually @medard if you see the html below all elements after header are in fixed position for eg- .content class is a fixed position where you know we have to mention a top:xyz number. That's the reason i am giving height to header. Lets assume i remove the height fro header which resolve my issue but what about the .content how will I make that position in its place

Comment: What I am trying to say is that i will be diffucult for you to achieve responsiveness with fixed pixels values. Unless you are prepared to do a lot of @media queries, which is not going to be prettry. You will have to use percentage as well for the .content div underneath. I have edited my answer with that.

Comment: I got your point but even i change my css and make it to percentage instead of pixels. But when i set 
`header img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}`
the header image become strachable

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can alter image attributes on window resize using jquery by following way...

`$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).height() < AAA) {
        $('header img').height(AAA);
    }
});`

In above code AAA means no of pixels.

Comment: It should be dynamic right ?? isn't it? I mean I can't set any height in pixels

Comment: well to handle different size, you need to specify and add conditions in jquery for different window size set different image size like following way...

`$(window).resize(function () {
 if ($(window).height() < AAA) {
  $('header img').height(AAA);
 }
 if ($(window).height() < BBB) {
  $('header img').height(BBB);
 }
 if ($(window).height() < CCC) {
  $('header img').height(CCC);
 }
});`

Comment: no it won't be possible actually to add different images in code, I think there must be any other way..

Comment: Then alternate solution is adding wrapper to the image element and set it's height and width in % and not in fixed position and then set image height and width to 100% and try to resize page for getting proper result..

Comment: I did what you said but it disturb's the whole layout like scroller is coming which I don't required and tht's only the reason i have to keep fixed position